# react - is it possible to globalize some variables and use them everywhere without import

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design, react-responsive

I am using [react-responsive](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-responsive) in development.

Let's say I have a file called `responsive.js`.

```
  const isBigScreen = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 1824px)' })
  const isTabletOrMobile = useMediaQuery({ query: '(max-width: 1224px)' })
  const isPortrait = useMediaQuery({ query: '(orientation: portrait)' })
  const isRetina = useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-resolution: 2dppx)' })
```

I want to use these variable without import them in every file. Is it possible?

For example,
A.jsx

```
...
  return <div>
    <h1>Device Test!</h1>
    {isDesktopOrLaptop && <p>You are a desktop or laptop</p>}
    {isBigScreen && <p>You  have a huge screen</p>}
  </div>
```

B.jsx

```
  ...
  return <div>
    <h1>Device Test!</h1>
    {isDesktopOrLaptop && <p>You are a desktop or laptop</p>}
    <p>Your are in {isPortrait ? 'portrait' : 'landscape'} orientation</p>
    {isRetina && <p>You are retina</p>}
  </div>
```

`Vue.js` have [vue-mq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-mq) which can achieve what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you absolutely cannot use hooks like this. Hooks in React are made to be called synchronously on the top level of a component and in every single rerender, in the very same order. [Check the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html)

```js
function Component() {
  // This is correct
  const myValue = useMyHook();
  ...
}

// This is incorrect
const myValue = useMyHook();

function Component() {
  ...
}

// This is also incorrect
function Component(props) {
  if (props.someValue) return ...
  
  // useMyHook will not be called on every rerender
  // and this will break React
  const myValue = useMyHook();
  ...
}
```

That said, you can extract your logic into custom hooks

```js
export const useBigScreen = () => useMediaQuery({ query: '(min-width: 1824px)' });
export const usePortrait = () => useMediaQuery({ query: '(orientation: portrait)' })
```

And use them like

```
function Component() {
  const isPortrait = usePortrait();

  // do something with isPortrait
  ...
}
```

You'll still need to import/export those unless you use a build level library like [unplugin auto import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unplugin-auto-import)